# Is there any way to dynamically change the size of an input field using knockout observables?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is there any way to dynamically change the size attribute of the input field using knockout observables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, by using `attr` binding (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html)

Example:

```
<input data-bind="attr: { size: someObservable }" />
```

Comment: Thanks.  That was perfect.  As an aside, I needed both size and value bindings, so I used  <input data-bind="value: value, attr: {size:field_size}" />